# Azure Data Factory v2 - Web Activity - Post Request to HTTPS self-signed Certificate

Tags: azure, post, https, azure-data-factory, self-signed

I have a web server which set up a self-signed certificate.

When I use Web Activity from ADF v2 to send a post request to the HTTPS URL, I got the error message:

"Error calling the endpoint 'https://...'. Response status code: ''. More details:Exception message: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'.No response from the endpoint. Possible causes: network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or timeout.

Is there anyway that I can cancel the Web Activity server certificate validation or any workaround that makes the Web Activity works with Self-signed certificate?

I have been stuck with this problem for few days so your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#linked-service-properties), should be exactly what you are looking for.
[image]

Also, in times of free certificates from Let's Encrypt, can't you get a proper cert?